# Connect with azure private endpoint API

Tags: azure, private, endpoint

I have an azure app service configured with private endpoint. I want to connect one of the APIs of private endpoint from another public azure app service. How can I do it?

Comment: Hi Arun, 
Are you saying that one app service (App Service A) has private endpoints configured. And, now you want this app service (App service A) to call another api?

Comment: Hi Sujit, the scenario is different. I have one app service (App Service A) has private endpoints configured, in which I have an API (API 1). I have another app service (App Service B) which is a public/normal azure app service. I want to connect API 1 from app service B.

Comment: Ohh ok, 

Your App service B should have vent integration enabled. If you can use same vnet where private endpoint for app service a is deployed it will work fine. 

if app service b is in different tenant and for any reason you cannot integrate with same net, you can deploy another private endpoint within vnet of app service B.
Remember to configure dns to translate private link fqdn to your private IP address linked to private endpoint.